# Christofides algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I'm trying to implement it from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) but the step **3** confuses me:

> 1. Create a minimum spanning tree T of G.
> 2. Let O be the set of vertices with odd degree in T. By the handshaking lemma, O has an even number of vertices.
> 3. *Find a minimum-weight perfect matching M in the induced subgraph given by the vertices from O*.
> 4. Combine the edges of M and T to form a connected multigraph H in which each vertex has even degree.
> 5. Form an Eulerian circuit in H.
> 6. Make the circuit found in previous step into a Hamiltonian circuit by skipping repeated vertices (shortcutting).

Induced subgraph *I* (from odd vertices of O) is taken over G, so it is complete as well as G so there will be multiple perfect matchings.

All Hungarian/Munkres algorithms which I've seen work with [Edmonds matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds_matrix). To get Edmonds from an arbitrary complete graph I have to 1) split graph into 2 sets of vertices *U*, *V* 2) having a split done, perform a minimum matching search in it.

Choosing different sets *U, V* will give different minimum perfect matchings weight. So the question is how to get a minimum perfect matching in *I* having a distance matrix of *I*.

Comment: The induced subgraph is only using the vertices of O (those with odd degree in T) - there are helpful examples with images on that wiki page...

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question.